# Problem calling procedure in protected object using access type

Tags: ada

Consider attached code showing three different calls to the same procedure. It compiles good but hangs up in execution time. I suspect about some kind of lock but I can not understand why.

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Exceptions; use Ada.Exceptions;
procedure Main is

   type A_Proc is access protected procedure (B: in out Integer);

   protected Obj is
      procedure Inc (B: in out Integer);
      procedure Test (B: in out Integer);
   end Obj;
   protected body Obj is
      procedure Inc (B: in out Integer) is
      begin
         B:=B+1;
      end Inc;
      procedure Test (B: in out Integer) is
         Proc : A_Proc:=Inc'Access;
      begin
         Proc.all (B);
      end Test;
   end Obj;

   B : Integer:=1;

   Proc : A_Proc:=Obj.Inc'Access;
begin
   Put_Line(B'Image);
   Obj.Inc (B);
   Put_Line(B'Image);
   Proc.all (B);
   Put_Line(B'Image);
   Obj.Test (B);
   Put_Line(B'Image);
   Put_Line("The End");
end Main;
```

Comment: It works when I compile and run it. What version of tools are you using?

Comment: More to the point, I think, @JimRogers, is what version _you_’re using?

Comment: I know in one of your other questions, you were messing around with maps of strings to procedure calls. If that was something you were still interested in, do you want answers on how to convert this example into something where you can call procedures using strings?  Simon has already answered the "why", so I am basically asking that if you want something like that, to update your question to reflect what kind of solution you might want to this issue.  I have a few ideas, but they depend on what your requirements really are.

Comment: I am using GPS 2018 (20180523) hosted on x86_64-pc-mingw32
GNAT Community 2018 (20180523-73)

Comment: @JimRogers, using the same (but dated ..0525) compiler on Debian stretch, it hangs after printing the '3' line

Comment: Interesting. Could this be a difference in underlying OS behaviors?

Answer (score 3):

In [ARM 9.5.1(3)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-9-5-1.html#p3), we find

> For the execution of a call on a protected subprogram, [...] If the call is an internal call (see 9.5), the body of the subprogram is executed as for a normal subprogram call. If the call is an external call, then the body of the subprogram is executed as part of a new protected action on the target protected object

and in [ARM 9.5(2,3)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-9-5.html#p2),

> When a name or prefix denotes an entry, protected subprogram, [...] the name or prefix determines a target object, as follows:
>
> - If it is a direct_name or expanded name that denotes the declaration (or body) of the operation, then the target object is implicitly specified to be the current instance of the task or protected unit immediately enclosing the operation; a call using such a name is defined to be an *internal call*

but, in [(5)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-9-5.html#p5),

> - If the name or prefix is a dereference (implicit or explicit) of an access-to-protected-subprogram value, then the target object is determined by the prefix of the Access attribute_reference that produced the access value originally; a call using such a name is defined to be an *external call*

so I’m afraid that the ARM explicitly warns against what you’re trying to do; `Obj` is locked on entry to `Obj.Test`, and the external call via `Proc` attempts to take the lock again. See [DeeDee’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54722516/40851).

Answer (score 3):

As an addendum to the answer by Simon Wright, I think that [ARM 9.5.1 (15)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-9-5-1.html#p15) ,

> During a protected action, it is a bounded error to invoke an operation that is potentially blocking. The following are defined to be potentially blocking operations:
>
> [...]
>
> - an external call on a protected subprogram (or an external requeue) with the same target object as that of the protected action;

and [ARM 9.5.1 (17)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-9-5-1.html#p17),

> If the bounded error is detected, Program_Error is raised. If not detected, the bounded error might result in deadlock or a (nested) protected action on the same target object.

also apply. If so, then performing an external call on a protected subprogram *might* result in a deadlock, but it *might* also result in the program continue to run (or a Program_Error to be raised).

I executed the program on GNAT CE 2018 both Windows and Linux (Debian). The program on Windows runs till the end, but hangs on Linux after printing 3.

---

To elaborate on the comments below: you may use the configuration pragma `Detect_Blocking` to make the Ada run time check for these potentially blocking calls (see [ARM H.5](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-H-5.html)).

If you use GPRbuild, then you can enable the detection by putting `pragma Detect_Blocking;` into a file (typically named `gnat.adc`) and reference this configuration file in you're project file by adding the `Local_Configuration_Pragmas` attribute to the compiler package (see also [here](https://docs.adacore.com/gnat_ugn-docs/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/the_gnat_compilation_model.html#configuration-pragmas) and [here](https://docs.adacore.com/gprbuild-docs/html/gprbuild_ug/gnat_project_manager.html#tools-options-in-project-files)):

```
project Default is

   for Source_Dirs use ("src");
   for Object_Dir use "obj";
   for Main use ("main.adb");

   package Compiler is
      for Local_Configuration_Pragmas use "gnat.adc";
   end Compiler;

end Default;
```

Comment: On macOS, the configuration pragma `Detect_Blocking` [(ARM 9.5.1(22.1)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-9-5-1.html#p22.1)) results in PE being raised.

Comment: Hope you don’t mind, I took the liberty of editing your links to directly reference the ARM para - to reference (19), add `#p19` to the end of the URL. This only works on the 2012 ARM (and presumably later editions).

Comment: @SimonWright No, not at all, thanks for the tip regarding the URLs. For the pragma `Detect_Blocking`: same behavior on Linux and Windows; a `Program_Error` is raised.